# PowerPlans are missing & hidden

Tags: windows-10

[Win10, 21H1, 19043.928]

Under Power-Plans, there are no choice to change from `Balanced` (i.e. to `Performance` plan):
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

When clicking `Create` neither it shows anything other than `Balanced` (even without any checkboxes):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

and even while trying to modify any setting, only a few options there:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Neither [this](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/107613-add-remove-ultimate-performance-power-plan-windows-10-a.html) or [this](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/110372-restore-missing-default-power-plans-windows-10-a.html) or [this](https://thegeekpage.com/missing-power-plans/) worked. What could be a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

All recent Windows builds (roughly two years ago and since) have only had the Balanced Plan and no others.

Power Options (display, sleep and lid actions) are now in the Windows Setting screen.

On my machines, Create New Plan shows 2 new plans, but machines are different and your machine may not offer additional plans. That is normal.

Power Plans are not hidden, however. Everything below starts with Control Panel, Power Options both Windows 10 and Windows 11.

Once you have a Custom Plan or decide to use Balanced and modify it, you can do basic settings in the Windows Settings screen and then use Advanced Power options for detailed settings.

The first screen below shows Lid and Button actions.

See the 2 main screen shots below.

[image: Windows 10 Main Power Plan]

...

[image: Windows Power additional plans]

...

Here are the Advanced Settings. There are fewer of these now as settings have drifted to the main window. This is somewhat of a work in progress.

[image: Advanced power settings]

..

One thing you might do if you still can't see all I showed here is go to the Computer Manufacturer's support site and update / reinstall the Power Driver.